# Error on Clip Raster By Mask Layer (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, clip, extract-by-mask

Can not seem to figure out this problem when i am running Clip Raster by Mask Layer function:

>
INFO    gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline "C:/Users/user/Downloads/gis files/final 23.05.2020.shp" -cl "final 23.05.2020" -crop_to_cutline crs=EPSG:3857&format&type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0 "C:/Users/user/Downloads/gis files/tst.tif"
2020-05-23T18:09:16     INFO    GDAL execution console output

```
         FAILURE: No target filename specified.

         Usage: gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]

          [-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]* [-novshiftgrid]

          [-order n | -tps | -rpc | -geoloc] [-et err_threshold]

          [-refine_gcps tolerance [minimum_gcps]]

          [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]

          [-ovr level|AUTO|AUTO-n|NONE] [-wo "NAME=VALUE"] [-ot Byte/Int16/...] [-wt Byte/Int16]

          [-srcnodata "value [value...]"] [-dstnodata "value [value...]"] -dstalpha

          [-r resampling_method] [-wm memory_in_mb] [-multi] [-q]

          [-cutline datasource] [-cl layer] [-cwhere expression]

          [-csql statement] [-cblend dist_in_pixels] [-crop_to_cutline]

          [-of format] [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-overwrite]

          [-nomd] [-cvmd meta_conflict_value] [-setci] [-oo NAME=VALUE]*

          [-doo NAME=VALUE]*

          srcfile* dstfile



         Available resampling methods:

          near (default), bilinear, cubic, cubicspline, lanczos, average, mode, max, min, med, Q1, Q3.

         Required parameter missing -

         The system cannot find the file specified.

         'url' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

         operable program or batch file.

         'zmax' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

         operable program or batch file.

         'zmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

         operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Not sure if you can consider XYZ tiles as rasters. That's probably why it's not working

Comment: Isn't the base-map a raster file? Embarrassed. What i am trying to accomplish is the equivalent of "clip to extent" available in arcgis.

Comment: Wondering if anyone could help on this? Is there another way to make this happen? Basically, i just want the basemap to only show on the background of the area covered by "Komunat_Finale" polygon: https://ibb.co/j5XKfvw

Comment: Is this for display purposes only? Duplicate polygon layer and use a inverted polygon renderer on top of the basemap to mask it.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto Yes, for display purposes only. Could you please elaborate how i can use that feature, or kindly lead me to some guides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a vector layer with a polygon, you can use it to visually mask other layers. Open the layer styling panel (F7)

[image]

Click the symbol render option.

[image]

Select the inverted polygons option. Then choose the make color. In this case I choose white and no stroke.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @Alexandre Neto! This worked perfectly.

Comment: What about is not for Visual only, but rather want to save a clipped raster as  .tif?

Comment: Please disregard the previous comment, I worked this out. For others trying to do this: 'Export' - 'Save As' ... the placed XYZ layer as a Rendered Image, (don't check 'Create VRT'), set the extent to whatever works for your purpose, map canvas or a 'create from layer' (ie. the eventual mask poly), set resolution to hor-10 x vert-10, then Run. Now you can clip the new .tif with 'Raster' + 'Extraction',+ 'Clip Rater by Mask Layer'.