# Is it possible to extract tiles layer as raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tiles, overlapping-features, zoom, extract

Let's say I have a shapefile that contains multiple polygons and I open it on QGIS:

[image]

Let's also say that I activate the OpenStreetMap tiles layer under it:

[image]

I'd like to find a way to extract the tiles layer under the polygons as a raster layer. Is it possible to do something like this while controlling the level of zoom that I want (since on different levels of zoom I have different images) in QGIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can export OSM XYT Tiles background map as raster file: right click on the OpenStreetMap layer and select `Export / Save as...` to save a copy of the background tiled map as raster file. Be sure to define the extent and resolution of the raster.

To get the extent of a layer, simply click `Calculate from Layer...` in the `Extent` section of the dialog window (see dialog window on the right in the screenshot, in dem middle). If you only want to keep those pixels that intersect the polygons, use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Clip raster by mask layer` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#clip-raster-by-mask-layer)).

However, you don't write why you need to do so, what you ultimately want to do with this raster. Maybe there are better ways to achieve that.

*OSM XYZ Tiles map (brighter, in the background), and exported raster file (darker, in the middle):*
[image]

Note Tile Usage policies, for example OSM Carto servers run by OpenStreetMap Foundation ( see https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/ ) heavily discourage bulk tile downloading and

> In particular, downloading an area of over 250 tiles at zoom level 13 or higher for offline or later usage is forbidden.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing a step. But I'm getting the raster of the [current visible screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SjUE9c-ms4J2T4nMCbjOwV6pL8FDB4du/view?usp=sharing). Should it work for getting the intersection of all the polygons from a layer with the tiles layer?

Comment: I didn't describe my ultimate goal because it'd be too broad, but it's getting the image from all parks that I have in a city in a raster. I've already [extracted the shapefile from OSM](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GNJ3OvQMq4XuqJWGmg6rR8_N6N8sUtKJ/view?usp=sharing). The next step will be to separate the small polygons that I have in it... But that I asked in [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415767/seeking-gis-tool-to-automatically-extract-polygon-geometries-from-images)... I think your suggestion of solution in that question would work fine for that. :)

Comment: To get the extent of a layer, simply click `Calculate from Layer...` in the `Extent` section of the dialog window (see dialog window on the right in the screenshot, in dem middle).

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening wrong. But when I try the procedure from your answer I get exactly the same error from [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362759/error-on-clip-raster-by-mask-layer-qgis)... The solution there also seems to work for me though, probably it'll be better to open a new question because the problem that I'm having now is a different one...

Comment: I understood what was the problem with the procedure. Apparently, I can't use the functionality `Clip raster by mask layer` on a  XYZ tiles map... I need first to get a raster layer from the tiles map and after that, I clip the raster with the polygons... Then it works fine!